# How can I host a Mercurial repository for several users myself?

Tags: mercurial, hosting, dvcs, collaboration

There are a number of hosting services for git, Mercurial, etc. I need to host my own, because some of the data we want to keep there is of a sensitive nature, and we cannot move it off-site.

I need to host a Mercurial repository on a server so that a number of people can access it to both pull changes and push their own work. There needs to be some kind of password protection, and it could also use ssh. I would prefer HTTP(S) as the transfer protocol (a la Google Code) though, if possible.

Can somebody point me to a description of how to do this? I have only found descriptions for hosting single-user repositories and hosting services so far, but nothing about doing the multi-user hosting myself.

Comment: Kiln (http://kilnhg.com) can host Mercurial repositories on your machine, uses HTTP(s) as its protocol, and has a bunch of simple configuration for permissions/multiple users/authentication/etc.  Disclaimer: I'm one of the Kiln devs.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Have a look at the [PublishingRepositories](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/index.cgi/PublishingRepositories) page on the mercurial site. It will tell you how to set up the `hgwebdir.cgi` script for serving multiple repos over https.

Once you've configured it, I would recommend adding this to your hgrc:

```
[web]
style = gitweb
```

I find it's a bit nicer theme than the default.

Comment: Wow, how did I miss that? Thanks! I guess I saw the line at the top where it says that people can pull changes and then didn't read on. Or something. Anyway, that answers my question, thank you!